# Multiple tables with different properties in a single Azure Search index

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Say I have multiple tables like News and User. These tables have complete different properties, is it possible to get data from both tables in the same index?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can index data from different sources into the same index. Here's a tutorial on how to achieve this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/tutorial-multiple-data-sources

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. I am not sure if this solves my question because in this tutorial you have 2 datasets, hotels and rooms. In this case rooms will be a property of hotels and that is not what I want. The tabels I have dont have any relations to other tabels, so they should be their own standalone data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating your index programaticaly then just create new ViewModel that is composed of multiple models and create the index out of it. Or create the composite view in database out of few tables and again just create the index based on that view.